# How do you check if a file is in a certain directory using PHP?

Tags: php, directory, dir

When accessing a file in PHP, it's possible to escape from the directory using ".." which can lead to a security risk. Is there any way to validate that a file is in a specified directory? There doesn't seem to be a built-in function for it.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a secure way to check if the file exists in the expected location.. you should do the following.

```
$base     = '/expected/path/';
$filename = realpath($filename);
if ($filename === false || strncmp($filename, $base, strlen($base)) !== 0) {
    echo 'Missing file or not in the expected location';
}
else {
    echo 'The file exists and is in the expected location';
}
```

Comment: i would also realpath() the $base folder just to make sure the slashes are aligned in same direction

Comment: This adds additional overhead to do this. If you're worried about the slash direction just use the PHP define `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`

Answer (score -4):

There is a very good example on php.net

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

```
<?php
$filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
?>
```

Comment: -1 because you didn't address how to protect against having ".." in the input path.